# run bash command from .NetCore with arguments

Tags: c#, .net, bash, sh, .net-core

I am trying to run one .NetCore program from another.

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "sh";
        psi.Arguments = "-c dotnet /home/myuser/PublishOutput/myprogram.dll";
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = psi
        };


        proc.Start();

        string error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
            return "error: " + error;

        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        proc.WaitForExit();

        return output;
```

As output I get:

> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 1.1.0   Build    :
>   928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86
>
> Usage: dotnet [common-options] [[options] path-to-application]
>
> Common Options:   --help                           Display .NET Core
>   Shared Framework Host help.   --version                        Display
>   .NET Core Shared Framework Host version.
>
> Options:   --fx-version            Version of the installed
>   Shared Framework to use to run the application.
>   --additionalprobingpath    Path containing probing policy and assemblies to probe for.
>
> Path to Application:   The path to a .NET Core managed application,
>   dll or exe file to execute.
>
> If you are debugging the Shared Framework Host, set 'COREHOST_TRACE'
>   to '1' in your environment.
>
> To get started on developing applications for .NET Core, install the
>   SDK from:   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

So I seems exacly like run command *dotnet* with no dll path argument.

Comment: What namespace is `ProcessStartInfo` from?

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the argument to `-c` so that it is one single argument:

```
psi.Arguments = "-c \"dotnet /home/myuser/PublishOutput/myprogram.dll\"";
```

Comment: Still the same problem. I added quotation marks and I got the same answer.

Comment: Is it exactly the same error message? I tried that sample code and it worked. If the dll path is wrong you should get a message like `No executable found matching command`

Comment: Yes. Exacly the same.

Comment: What if there are spaces in the path and therefore quotes are required in the argument? Switch to single quotes?

Comment: @formicini i'd try double escaping first - `\\\"`

Answer (score 4):

i change something and make the message can be output sync

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExecuteCommandX
{
 /// <summary>
///  sample by linkanyway@gmail.com
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args"></param>
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedParameter.Local
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ping",
            Arguments = "-c 3 8.8.8.8",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };

        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = psi
        };

        proc.Start();



        Task.WaitAll(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }), Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!proc.StandardError.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = proc.StandardError.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }));


        proc.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(proc.ExitCode);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a Linux program with specific commands (e.g. `find / -name image.png`) from your c# .net core application, you can use the following snippet:

```cs
            try
            {
                var process = new Process();
                var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = $"/bin/bash",
                    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory = "/mnt",
                    Arguments = $"-c \"find / -name image.png\"",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                };
                process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                process.Start();

                String error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                String output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //_logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
                throw;
            }
```

Notes on the arguments:

- **FileName = $"/bin/bash"** for all shell commands you might use that
- **WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory** = "/mnt" just an example, this directory is important if the command you're running needs files (e.g. file.png) it will than look relative to the working directory to fetch the file
- **Arguments = $"-c "find / -name image.png""** runs the following command in cli: /bin/bash -c "find / -name image.png"

`-c` is mandatory for it to work, as written in [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> -c string
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments >after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.