# How to get the current user of the Ubuntu system in Asp .Net core 2.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm having a requirement to identify the current logged in user in Ubuntu system. In windows I can use

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

to get the username. I'm confused how to do that for Linux. Any suggestions?

I want the current logged in user in the controller.

```
public ControllerName(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath; 
            var user = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;/* System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString(); */
        }
```

But `User` is returning null always.

Comment: Can you share more details code of where do you want to get the current logged in user?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I've edited the question?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core identity for login?

Comment: @TanvirArjel No. I'm not using it. In that case is there any other way to get the user name?

Comment: Oh! then how do you storing logged-in user information in session? What is your logged in mechanism?

Comment: @TanvirArjel It's like I want to get the username of the user logged in to the machine. Like in windows if I use the above command I'll get the cuurent user of windows. Is there any way to get the logged in user in Ubuntu?

Comment: Oh! Understood! Then this would not work! This is only for Getting the logged in user in ASP.NET Core web application, not in the machine. You can ask a separate question or modify this question specifying what exactly you are wanting. Hope someone will answer you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by executing terminal command `whoami` from the .Net core application.

You can refer the below links for some idea.

1)[run bash command from .NetCore with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874439/run-bash-command-from-netcore-with-arguments)

2)https://loune.net/2017/06/running-shell-bash-commands-in-net-core/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the user *name*:

```cs
Environment.UserName
```